# Distribute Titanium iPad App to work iPads

Tags: ios, ipad, titanium, appcelerator

I have created an iPad app using Appcelerator Titanium for the company I work for.  This is an app that we can only use in my company, and do not want to try and distribute it through the app store.  Is there a way to distribute this app to the company iPads without them being connected to my developers program?

Comment: I am not that familiar with Appcelerator, but is this app still compiled and built using Xcode?  Also - is your company currently registered as an enterprise developer through Apple?  If not, have you checked to see if you can register via the enterprise developer program?

Comment: Indirectly - you write JavaScript code which is translated into native code at runtime. You still need to be a paid up Apple Developer with a Mac also.

Comment: Yes I have an apple ios developers licences

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could (for example) create a website where people can download your app (.ipa) and the provisioning profile (distribution). People can open that website on their device and "download" both files. Make sure to only do this for internal use as Apple will not like to see you distributing apps to the public like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for in-house apps. Here's how the process works

1. Register for the iOS Developer Enterprise Program.
2. Prepare your app for distribution.
3. Create an enterprise distribution provisioning profile that authorizes devices to use apps you’ve signed.
4. Build the app with the provisioning profile.
5. Deploy the app to your users.

You should package the app using Titanium Studio or create an archive using XCode and then choose in-house distribution in XCode Organizer.

Comment: But how does one "...package the app using Titanium Studio"? That seems like the point of the question. How does one generate an IPA with Titanium Studio?